# taking location and sending sms

Tags: android, sms, location

The code below is giving me the Location of the phone but the msges are not getting sent.

When I give the sms code before location manager deceleration it sends the msg or before try.

```
try{

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        String message;
         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
         String loc=location.toString();
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), loc,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         String  phoneNumber="5556";
         message="this is amog and it is my current location "+loc;
         sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);

         }    

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

};



    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: have you initiate the SmsManager ?
1st check the permission 
<"uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/">
after that 
add the following if not added 
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
  sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);

Comment: that is done  private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {        
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);                
         SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
         
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
     }